# Alternatives to quick links?

Tags: navigation, ux-field, hyperlinks, alternatives

I have some links in sub menus, e.g. animals> dog, cat, rabbit and most of the users are interested in cats, is it good idea to make cats link as a quick link? If not, what is good alternative to quick links in this case?[image]

Comment: Can you clarefy your question a little big? What is a quick link and what is a normal link? These are not standard terms.

Comment: Quicklinks  is a list of unstructured links placed in a salient place on a page. Sub menu links are structured links nested under parent link

Comment: Might be handy if you provide what platform this if for so people can give you mock-up ideas. Is this on mobile, desktop, tablet etc?

Answer (score 1):

Another alternate is, if you want to see it in more minimal just put the simple Quick link "Animal" in your home/landing page, don't put dropdown in here. and when the Quick links clicked , its redirect to the animal page and  you can show the sub categories in that page like bellow image [image]

and if you want to keep your original design concept and want to changes in UI then bellow is one of the good suggestion for you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use a table of content side navigation with the heading "On this page" for desktop and dropdown for mobile. Here is an article on the topic: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/in-page-links/

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to keep your navigation as it is and create a section pushing the cat page on your home/landing page.

This way your navigation will stay clear and organized and you can be more flexible. If in six months, your users prefer dogs, you can just change the content of your new section.

Plus it reveals a bit of your content which is a good thing for a homepage.

Something like this.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm astonished that there are people who don't know what a quick link is. About 3 or 4 years ago it was the rage in design to place a row of two or three quick links  so a user didn't have to search through menus to get the most important information.  ie - about us, contact us, email, etc.

It is a good idea, but the problem is it's now no longer a trend so most users don't know to look for those links at the top of the page anymore.If they are big, or if there is a high contrast, or a bright color to bring the eye to that area, it's a great idea in my opinion. Go for it.

Answer (score 0):

My preference is **search**.  It's fine to use hierarchy to make data easier to manage, but don't expect users who are not familiar with the organizational structure to find anything with it.  The animal kingdom is organized by hierarchy.  Would you really expect anyone to find info about animals by navigating the domain-kingdom hierarchy?

I recommend you avoid hardcoding any "quick links".  What if demographics change so that turtles are all the rage?  Or a hamster fad pops up?

Many sites nowadays have a group of automatically generated links labeled "Popular" or "Trending".  **Consider doing A/B testing to determine whether such links would be of any benefit to users.**